# How can I get a list of the topics from a ActiveMQ broker?

Tags: activemq-classic

I found this on ActiveMQ tutorial: http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-topics-and-queues-in-a-broker.html

But I really cannot figure out how to get the topics. Can you give me an example, I mean,  programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on what you are looking to do here.  ActiveMQ has extensive [JMX APIs](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) for monitoring an managing the broker, there's a ton of articles out there on using them to list queues and topics, a quick google search found [this one](http://java.dzone.com/articles/managing-activemq-jmx-apis).  You can also take advantage of ActiveMQ's [Advisory Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) if you don't want to use JMX.

Comment: I tried the example you gave to me but it doesn't work. And I got the exception `[Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]`